# Unable to get Groovy version from GroovySystem, trying InvokerHelper

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, groovy

we are using groovy on a java + maven project and getting below error during the build:

```
INFO] Unable to get Groovy version from GroovySystem, trying InvokerHelper.
[ERROR] Your Groovy version (1.1-rc-1) doesn't support compilation.  The minimum version of Groovy required is 1.5.0.  Skipping compiling.
```

My pom.xml have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
 <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
 <version>2.4.12</version>
 <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, it works for me:

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.7</version>
            <type>pom</type> 
     </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem. in my case, groovy-all.jar was corrupted. if it is so you can do followings

remove

> $USER_FOLDER\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-all

then

> Right click on the project click Maven->Update Project

as shown below image.

[image: eclipse project update]